# CircleCI fails on error in YAML

Tags: javascript, yaml, circleci

I copied the deployment section straight from their example:

```
machine:
  environment:
    PATH: ${PATH}:${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/node_modules/.bin
    NODE_ENV: test
    TZ: Europe/Paris
  node:
    version: v0.12.7

dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - node_modules
    - app/js/lib
  override:
    - npm prune && npm install

deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - ./deploy_prod.sh
  staging:
    branch: staging
    commands:
      - ./deploy_staging.sh
```

and yet I get this:

[image]

Ideas?

Comment: Most likely you got some funky character when you copied the code from the page. Try writing it for hand.

Comment: Progress. progress. now it doesn't fail but doesn't run deployment at all.